# Sum N elements in excel

Tags: excel, sum

I don't know how calculate sum without VBA in MS Excel. I have number in cell A1 and I need calculate

[1 http://imageshack.us/scaled/thumb/811/msp2471b9b212d265i5h330.gif](http://imageshack.us/scaled/thumb/811/msp2471b9b212d265i5h330.gif) , where n is a number in A1 cell.

I solve  as follows: in row 2 I add array formula
`{=IF(COLUMN() <= B1; 1/FACT((3 * COLUMN())); "")}`
and then calculate SUMM of all elements in row. But this solution contains computation steps.

Comment: You could mention what you've tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUM(1/FACT((3*ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A" & B1)))))
```

where n is in B1. Enter as an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

**Note** this will error when n>56 (at least on my Excel is does) because (3*56)! is too large a number. Still, that's not a problem, because you cross Excel's decimal precision limit long before that.

Comment: this calculate 1/(3x)! not summ of 1 to n.

Comment: @nekitozzz  When entered as an array formula (as Tim specified) it _does_ calculate the sum